# Make only certain columns editable in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid, tablecolumn

I have a grid with multiple columns and I use the first column for a row label.  I looked at the example for making the grid editable, but that appears to make the whole grid editable.  Is there away to specify a certain column(s) only?

Answer (score 18):

Got it! By not setting the editor property on the column object the column is non-editable.